# Unicode issue in LateX

Tags: unicode

I want to enter unicode character `U+F3D9` into a LaTeX document that encodes in UTF8.

I've tried `\unicode{f3d9}` and `\symbol{F3D9}` to no avail.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: `\symbol{"F3D9}` or `^^^^f3d9`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/545497/35864

Comment: That unicode value is in the private use area.  You absolutely must have loaded a font that contains the symbol, and you must arrange for the font to be embedded in your final pdf output.