# How to call up characters of a font by their unicode number

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, unicode

[image]

I have a font here and I changed some letters with Fontforge. 
I used the following code to call up the font.

What I should know:
*How can I use the Unicode number instead of typing A or B or C, e.g. `\UTF{0042}` in that case.*

If necessary, I can also upload my ttf file.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Test: 
\newfontfamily{\myfont}[Scale=2]{test04.ttf}
ABCD\dots, but {\myfont ABCDE\dots H} 
%\UTF{0042}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just so I understand correctly: You have removed 'B' (U+0042) and 'C' (U+0043) from your font, but you still want to be able to print that character if you say something like `\UTF{0042}` in your file (but presumably not if you say `B`, because what would be the point of removing it from the file in that case)?

Comment: If my understanding in the comment above is correct, it would quite surprise me if that were possible. If the character is gone, it's gone - you can't get it back no matter what method you use to access it. Presumably a solution would be not to remove the letter from the font, but to park it somewhere else (in the private-use area) and access the letter via the new code-point (I have no idea if and how that would work).

Comment: @moewe  Oh.... new!!  And new picture.

Comment: No idea what is the point of  removing glyphs, but you can use \symbol or \char to access a character by number.

Comment: Do you mean something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/545497/35864: `\symbol{"0061}`/`\char"0061`/`^^^^0061`?

Comment: Ah, ok `\char"<unicodenumber>` or nicer \symbol{"<unicodenumber}`   works. Very good. ;)